# Postgres 12 restore

Tags: postgresql

I can't restore my Postgres server 12. I have cluster, 2 servers PSQL12s01, PSQL12s02. Between arch_log replication. Database size about 45 GB + 400 GB arch_log. On slave I run script

```sh
D=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
sudo -u postgres -H bash -c "pg_basebackup -l db_TECH_$D -D - -Ft -X fetch | bzip2 > /var/lib/postgresql/BKP/db_TECH_$D.tar.bz2"
```

The file is unpacked at REST Server and run docker container

```sh
docker run -d \
    --name tc12s02-postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
    -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
    -p 15432:5432 \
    -v /var/lib/postgresql/BKP:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
    -v /var/lib/postgresql/SMB/arch_log:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/arch_log \
    postgres:12
```

When a start container I have date on 2022-10-17

```sh
restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/arch_log/%f %p'
recovery_target_time = '2023-02-18 20:00:00'
recovery_target_action = 'promote'

touch recovery.signal
```

I don't know why I don't want to reach the data from arch_log. Maybe I have to do pg_basebackup for a master not on slave. I did not want to additionally burden the master

Comment: this seems more database admin than programming related; seems better suited to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ or maybe https://superuser.com/

Comment: Do you receive an error?